# How to marshal multiline to XML in Go?

Tags: xml, go, kml

I need to store coordinates to KML file. It should be like this:

```
<coordinates>
            51.600223,25.003058,0
            51.600223,25.003065,0
            51.600213,25.003065,0
            51.600212,25.003065,0
            51.600217,25.003075,0
</coordinates>
```

If I join the string and try to marshal as one string I get `&#xA` for every new line

```
KmlLineString struct {
    Coordinates string `xml:"coordinates"`
}
```

If I change it to `` Coordinates []string`xml:"coordinates"` ``  I get tags on every line.

How can I do this?

Comment: `&#xA;` represents a newline. When the XML is read and parsed, the value of the `<coordinates>` tag will contain the newline characters. What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Huh! Google maps consumes `&#xA;`! Thanks! I just need to compile KML file. Usually KML files have no `&#xA;` so I tried to find a way to remove it.

Comment: In case you want to make the xml more readable for humans you can use `,innerxml` which causes the encoder to write the contents *"verbatim, not subject to the usual marshaling procedure"*. https://go.dev/play/p/_9F-4RcBjT4

Comment: That's exactly what I looked for! Can you please move from comments, I will mark it as an answer?

Comment: @mkopriva, the OP failed to tag you, here we go ;-)

Comment: Care must be taken though when using `,innerxml`, as the value will not be escaped, and may result in invalid XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @icza points out in his comment, the `&#xA;` is an escaped new line and is the correct output when marshaling XML. Any valid XML decoder will be able to unmarshal that and understand what it represents.

If you want to output the literal new lines regardless, perhaps to make the XML human-friendly, then you can use the `,innerxml` tag option. This option instructs the encoder to marshal the content verbatim. However, as @icza points out in another comment, if the field that's tagged with `,innerxml` contains invalid XML, the result of marshaling such a field will also be invalid XML.

For example:

```golang
var xml_data = `<coordinates>
            51.600223,25.003058,0
            51.600223,25.003065,0
            51.600213,25.003065,0
            51.600212,25.003065,0
            51.600217,25.003075,0
</coordinates>`

type KmlLineString struct {
    Coordinates string `xml:",innerxml"`
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/kXOjZZ-DyHc

Or

```golang
var xml_data = `
            51.600223,25.003058,0
            51.600223,25.003065,0
            51.600213,25.003065,0
            51.600212,25.003065,0
            51.600217,25.003075,0
`

type KmlLineString struct {
    Coordinates Coordinates `xml:"coordinates"`
}

type Coordinates struct {
    Value string `xml:",innerxml"`
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/kiN-NUt67ny